# Adding jquery 2.0.3 breaks text-align for textboxes on IE10

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I'm seeing some weird behavior when using jQuery.  It's like it is doing something to the `input[type=text]` elements to make them act weird.

Note this jsFillder without jquery referenced.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3kk7/

```
<style>
    td.right input {
        text-align:right;
    }
</style>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="right">
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="testing">
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>    
  var td = document.getElementById("testing");
  td.className = "right";
</script>
```

When you click inside each of the textboxes, you see the same behavior.  The cursor is right aligned as to be expected.

Now when I add jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/3Nrzd/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Clicking on the javascript modified `className` does not right align the cursor.  After focusing on the second text box and start to enter some data, it will make it right aligned for the duration of the demo.

I have done this using the `$().css()` method with no difference.
I also have removed the `::ms-clear` pseudo element for giggles with no difference.

I would expect both textboxes to act the same since they are the same.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Ut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by adding `-ms-writing-mode: rl-tb;` rule:

```
td.right input {
    text-align:right;
    -ms-writing-mode: rl-tb;
}
```

Live fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/mNHJ6/

More information about proprietary `-ms-writing-mode` CSS property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Although this still feels like it is an issue with jquery 2.0.3, this is a solution that works.  

Thanks.